# Parse error again and again

Tags: php, mysql

This topic has been posted several times already but the solutions posted here in SO doesn't seem to help. I have checked on the semicolons, spaces and the query but I am still receiving the parse error on php whenever i call subjaccess.php.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a8367888/public_html/subjaccessrequest.php on line 14
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "database";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "password";

//$pass = $_POST['email'];
$pass = "blahblach@gmail.com";

$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die("Opps something went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops something went wrong");

$query =  "SELECT (a.acode) as "access_id", (s.s_first_name) as "fname",      (s.s_middle_initial) as "mname", (s.s_last_name) as "lname", (a.s_email) as "email", (a.req_subj) as "subjcode"
FROM access a, student s
WHERE a.s_email = s.s_email
AND a.t_email = '$pass' 
AND a.access_status = "pending";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $res[]=array('aid'=> $row['access_id'],'fname'=> $row['fname'],'mname'=> $row['mname'], 'lname'=> $row['lname'], 'email'=> $row['email'], 'subj'=> $row['subjcode']);
}

echo '$res';

$response['request'] = $res;
print(json_encode($response));
?>
```

Hoping for your responses.

Comment: check the quotes. You liar, you said you checked the query.

Comment: hell, even SO syntax highlighting shows the error!

Comment: is this your real password there?

Comment: Please learn the syntax _basics_ …

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
$query =  "SELECT (a.acode) as "access_id", (s.s_first_name) as "fname",      (s.s_middle_initial) as "mname", (s.s_last_name) as "lname", (a.s_email) as "email", (a.req_subj) as "subjcode"
```

to

```
$query =  "SELECT (a.acode) as 'access_id', (s.s_first_name) as 'fname',      (s.s_middle_initial) as 'mname', (s.s_last_name) as 'lname', (a.s_email) as 'email', (a.req_subj) as 'subjcode'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes in your string although it is surrounded by `"`. This breaks your PHP code. But you don't need them anyway. Also you should use a `JOIN` instead of `FROM a, b`. And all identifiers in a query should be quoted by backtics ` . The final query should look like this:

```
$query =  "
SELECT 
  `a`.`acode` AS `access_id`,
  `s`.`s_first_name` AS `fname`,
  `s`.`s_middle_initial` AS `mname`,
  `s`.`s_last_name` AS `lname`,
  `a`.`s_email` AS `email`,
  `a`.`req_subj` AS `subjcode`
FROM `access` `a`
JOIN `students` `s` 
  ON `a`.`s_email` = `s.s_email`
 AND `a`.`t_email` = '$pass' 
 AND `a`.`access_status` = 'pending'
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query =  "SELECT (a.acode) as " . access_id . ", (s.s_first_name) as " . fname . ",      (s.s_middle_initial) as " . mname . ", (s.s_last_name) as " . lname . ", (a.s_email) as "email", (a.req_subj) as " . subjcode
```